# Excel bar chart

Tags: excel, charts

I am trying to make a stacked 100% excel chart where the fill color of each series is the same, and borders (of a different color) only on the top of the box.  If I choose to edit the border, the only option I see is one that allows me to make the entire border for the series; i.e top, bottom and on the sides.  Can anyone please suggest how I can have border only on the top?
Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

You can't selectively format the edges of a bar in an Excel chart.

You could add another series with a small value (e.g. .1% of the total). This won't have a fillable rectangle, but it will still have a border that you can format.